# Associate Records using REST

Tags: javascript, rest, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to associate/disassociate records through REST with JS and jQuery by following the SDK sample ([Sample: Associate and Disassociate Records Using the REST Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh372956)).

I keep getting the same error on both cases:

> "Update operations are not supported for '$links' end points that refer to collection properties".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post any relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at a [simple example that creates and email and associates a sending user](http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/crmcustomereffective/archive/2011/12/06/using-the-crm-2011-rest-services-and-deep-insert-to-create-activities.aspx)